# How to declare functional component with generic props as a constant

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

This is how you would define a React component that accepts a generic type in its props:

```
type Props<T> {
  data: T;
}

export const MyComponent = <T,>(props: Props<T>) => {
  return (
  <div>whatever</div>;
  )
};
```

If I further wish to declare the type of the MyComponent functional component using `React.FC` how would I do it?

The following fails with `Cannot find type T`:

```
export const MyComponent : React.FC<OwnProps<T>> = <T,>(props: OwnProps<T>) => {
```

I know how to do it with `export function MyComponent`, my question is specifically whether I can add this type information using the `export const MyComponent` idiom.

Comment: You just can't.

Comment: There's been talk of ["React.FC being deprecated"](https://www.google.com/search?q=react.fc+deprecated) but AFAIK there is no *official* notice. Anyways,  click on any of the google search results linked and see why React.FC is terrible and should be avoided.

Answer (score -2):

`export const MyComponent: React.FC<Prop T> = ({ data }) => {}`

- within the angle brackets is your interface type
- data would be the props passed to your component